# Changing PHP "required" parameters breaks site structure

Tags: php

I've been tasked to make some alterations to a site. Specifically to change the main page to which the user is redirected when typing the site's URL. As it stands now, the user is immediately transferred to the "login" page as described in my "index.php":

**index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
$all_url = explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url = explode('/', $all_url[0]);

//Homepage
if (empty($url[1])) {
$url[1] = 'home';
}

//DB connect
$config = array(
'host' => 'localhost', //CHANGE THIS, DB SERVER
'user' => 'xxx', //CHANGE THIS, DB USER
'password' => 'xxx', //CHANGE THIS, DB PASSWORD
'database' => 'xxx' //CHANGE THIS, DB NAME
);
$DB = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $config['host'] . ';dbname=' . $config['database'], $config['user'], $config['password']);
$DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$DB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$DB->exec("SET names utf8");

if (file_exists('controller/' . $url[1] . '.php')) {

$gtpl = 'main';
if (empty($_SESSION['uid']) && $url[1]!='register') {
    //login
    require 'controller/login.php';

}else{
    require 'controller/' . $url[1] . '.php';
}

require 'view/' . $gtpl . '.php';
} else {
echo 'ERROR - File not found!!!';
}
?>
```

I want to make it so that the user is transferred to "home" instead of "login" and use the login form later in the site. Problem is - when I change the *require 'controller/login.php';* to *require 'controller/home.php';*, it redirects me to that page but I can't move to any other address in the site. What changes should would make it work propertly? I also provide the "main.php", just in case

**main.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap-theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui-1.10.3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/colpick.css">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <?php require 'view/frontend/'.$tpl.'.php';?>

    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.migrate.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/farbtastic.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/crop.img.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/colpick.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jquery.numeric.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/init.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean with " I can't move to any other address in the site"?

Comment: The script will always redirect to the home.php, because the user is not logged in. This is a logic problem, not a script problem. Try automatic login as a guest or something else.

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL It's a shop site, there is a "cart" function, registration etc. These do not work.

Comment: @user2315641 because you are redirecting user to home page if it is not logged in. You need to apply it only for restricted pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the **SESSION** *uid* property is never set. This is probably done by the login controller.

This means that the *else* clause of your code is never invoked.
Solution: use another flag, and redirect the user to home when it is not set. Set the flag after redirecting the user to home.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['firstVisit']) && $url[1]!='home') {
   $_SESSION['firstVisit'] = false; //ensures we never enter this clause again
   require 'controller/home.php';

}else{
   require 'controller/' . $url[1] . '.php';
}
```

Still, if you want some pages to be accessible only when the user is logged in you should handle it like this:

```
$restricted = array('page1','page2');  // restricted pages behind login

if (!isset($_SESSION['firstVisit']) && $url[1]!='home') {
   $_SESSION['firstVisit'] = false; //ensures we never enter this clause again
   require 'controller/home.php';
}else if (empty($_SESSION['uid']) && in_array($url[1], $restricted)) {
   //not logged in, but trying to access restricted page.
   require 'controller/login.php';
}else{
   require 'controller/' . $url[1] . '.php';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($_SESSION['uid']) && $url[1]!='register') {
    //login
    require 'controller/login.php';
}
```

you could change into :

```
$notrestricted = array('register','home'); 

if (empty($_SESSION['uid']) && !in_array($url[1], $notrestricted)) {
    //login
    require 'controller/login.php';
}
```

Comment: That didn't change anything. I don't want the user to be transferred to "home" when he's logged and to "login" if he's not. I want to completely disregard "login" as an option.